# Total Physical Memory retrieved from Win32_ComputerSystem doesn't match with DirectX tool value

Tags: c#, memory, wmi, ram, performancecounter

I am trying to retrieve the total physical memory available value of my machine through Win32_OperatingSystem class in C#. Below is how I am retrieving this value.

```
 ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        if (moc.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject MO in mc.GetInstances())
            {
                try
                {
                    computerSystemDetails["TotalPhysicalMemory"] = (MO["TotalPhysicalMemory"] == null) ? new string[] { } : new string[] { MO["TotalPhysicalMemory"].ToString() };
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error("GetSystemDetails", "Error occurred when retrieving the computer system information", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return computerSystemDetails;
```

The value I'm getting from the above is 16243 MB. But when I use DirectX Diagnostic tool I am getting the value 16384MB. What is the explanation for this difference? Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx) for that property explains why:

> Be aware that, under some circumstances, this property may not return an accurate value for the physical memory. For example, it is not accurate if the BIOS is using some of the physical memory. For an accurate value, use the Capacity property in Win32_PhysicalMemory instead.